# PHP MySQLi fetch_object() on empty string returns undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

It seems this problem has just recently come up for me (I don't remember having this issue in a similar scenario before). With the following code, php loops through and displays a form with values from a MySQL table. If any of the values contain an empty string I get the following notice:

`Notice: Undefined variable: row in /home/public_html/index.php on line XXX`

It ONLY happens when a string is empty.

This is the form code:

```
<?php
    for ($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {
      $val = $env->getVal("plan_title_$i,plan_desc_$i,plan_price_$i,plan_link_$i");
    }
?>
```

And the portion of getVal code pulling the data:

```
while ($tmp = $res->fetch_object()->$col) {
  $row[$keys[$i]] = trim((string)$tmp);
  $i++;
}
```

Now I've thought of giving the column a default value of a space since that seems to solve the notice problem. However that's not possible since it's a BLOB field.

Does anyone know how I can prevent $row from being undefined if the value pulled is an empty string? This only happens on empty strings.

Comment: more likely $keys[$i] is undefined

Comment: Do you mean that this row throws the error ` $row[$keys[$i]] = (string)$tmp;`

Comment: @Grumpy Unfortunately I'm 100% positive $keys[$i] is defined properly. It would kill the script earlier if it weren't.

Comment: @Melsi It doesn't throw an error, simply a notice saying $row is undefined when attempting to output from it. The line that says it's undefined is when getVal() returns $row.

Comment: Would it be possible to post more code including the getVal definition, this would allow to have the hole image of it.

Comment: @Melsi Sure no problem. Done. This wouldn't be so confusing if it weren't for only empty strings.

Comment: if the notice is shown by the return statement then it probably does not enters the while loop, did you put an echo 'hello'; inside the loop to be sure?

Comment: @Melsi If value initially contains a space before trim(), var_dump outputs an empty string. If value is an empty string, it stops looping through. So if plan_link_1 to 3 contain spaces and 4 contains nothing, 4 doesn't even exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4465/discussion-between-melsi-and-baez)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found in the chat this to be the solution:

```
while (($tmp = $res->fetch_object()->$col)!==null)
```

this will allow to enter the loop even when values in db are empty (empty strings). The while did not entered on empty values and this caused the return statement to show an undefined variable notice.